# He has only laid down for an hour today?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, lie-lay-lain-laid

I would like to express that a person has only reclined for an hour so far today.  Is it correct to say:

> He has only laid down for an hour so far today.

or is it perhaps:

> He has only lay down for an hour so far today.

Comment: You cannot use *has* with *lay*; *has* as an auxiliary indicates the perfect aspect, which would take the past participle form of *laid* or *lain*, depending on which verb you intend.

Comment: ...From the preamble, it's lain, pp of lie (the reclining one not the porkies one). However, it's not often used colloquially.

Comment: @choster are you answering my question or suggesting I change the question?  If answering, please submit it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth are you answering my question or suggesting I change the question?  If answering, please submit it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: No. For two reasons: this question has been asked on ELU before, and it was correctly closed on _that_ occasion for being unsuitable for this site ('general reference' can include books on basic grammar as well as dictionaries).

Comment: The only way the first would be correct would be if you had a drake laying the fine down of his breast feathers to pad his mate’s nest with. Otherwise, a person would have just lain there for an hour, since they laid nothing.

Comment: See [this diagram for more than you wanted to know about](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/3kindsofword.jpg) _lie_ and _lay_.

Answer (score -3):

Of the two options you provide, the first one ("laid down") is more accepted usage.

Comment: No it's not. They're equally unacceptable.